# Background color of view changes after view appears?

Tags: ios, swift

Okay so I set the background of my login screen to a certain color. I'm using firebase and when it doesn't detect an authentication, it instantiates the login view controller and presents it.

When it first shows up, it is the correct color, but then it gets darker right away. It kinda seems like the alpha goes back to normal 100%.

But if I use the same 2 lines of code on a logout button(in a tableview), the view comes up the correct color and doesn't change.

I can provide more info if needed. Thanks.

```
if(FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser == nil) {
            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firebaseLoginViewController")
            self.navigationController?.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

 switch(indexPath.row) {
        case 5:
            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firebaseLoginViewController")
            self.navigationController?.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

Comment: It seems that the viewController is presented more than one time. Please debug the view hierarchy in the Xcode.

Comment: Where did you check `if(FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser == nil)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when you present a view, the view behind it is removed after your view fills the screen. If your view has a semi transparent background color, then you'll notice when the other view is removed and the black window shows through.

You can fix this two ways. The first is obviously to use an alpha of 100% for your background color. However if you're looking for the semi transparent look on purpose, then you can see your `modalPresentationStyle`. There are several options for in your case I think the best would be `.overFullScreen`

Set it something like this before you present your viewController with a semi transparent background.

```
self.navigationController?.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
```

Comment: This is the answer to your question OP.  You could also use 
`modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext` for a modal feel similar to a webpage.  This will show the viewController over the "old" viewController but not take up all of the screen.